# Angular: Passing formGroup to child component does not trigger changes using controlContainer.control

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a small project with a parent component and a child component.
In my parent component I have a formArray in which I need to filter the correct formGroup to pass to child

EXAMPLE: (Parent Component)

```
<child-component [formGroup]="relevantForm"></child-component>
```

TypeScript:

```
   ngOnInit{
    setRelevantForm(id){
     this.relevantForm = this.formArray.controls.find(fa => fd.value.id === id);
    }
}
```

(Child Component) TypeScript:

```
constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer)

this.relevantForm = this.controlContainer.control
```

Now on my project I have a button to delete current relevantForm and after deletion
setRelevantForm(id) runs again and sets current formGroup, however in child component I would like to get notified on this change in order to update view.

I know there are different ways to achive like passing form in @Input()
like:

```
    <child-component [relevantForm]="relevantForm"></child-component>
     and in typeScript:

    @Input() relevantForm;
```

however, I do not know what is the right way to do so.
is there any possible way to know if the form has changed in child component using controlContainer?

in another words. I want to know when the **actual** form has changed and not values on its formControls.

hope my questions is clear.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`FormGroupDirective`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupDirective) to inject the form in all children components.
Note that this directive will inject the form only if `child-component` is inside the `form` tags

**parent**

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm>
    <child-component></child-component
</form
```

**child**

```js
constructor(private formGroupDirective: FormGroupDirective)

// Original form injected into the child
this.relevantForm = this.formGroupContainer.control
// To observe changes in the form
this.onFormChange = this.relevantForm.valueChanges
```